# How to solve this tricky integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

Hey I have a problem with this integral.
Seems complicated.

$$\int\frac{dx}{\cos 4x\cdot\sin 2x}$$

Comment: Have you tried u substitution with u = sin 2x?

Comment: multiply both numerator and denominator by $\sin 2x$, then change suitable variable.

Comment: take the half angle substitution

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Don’t worry, it is a bit complicated.
We’re getting rid of cos4x so we could substitute t=cos2x.

\begin{equation}
    \int \frac{dx}{cos4x\cdot sin2x}=\int \frac{sin2xdx}{\left (  2cos^{2}2x-1\right )sin^{2}2x}=\begin{vmatrix}
t=cos2x & \\ 
dt=-2sin2xdx & 
\end{vmatrix}=\int \frac{-\frac{1}{2}dt}{\left ( 2t^{2}-1 \right )\left ( 1-t^{2} \right )}=\frac{1}{4}\int\frac{dt}{\left ( t^{2}-\frac{1}{2} \right )\left ( t^{2}-1 \right )}
\end{equation}
Now we have integral with rational function so we separate it into two fractions:
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{4}\int\frac{dt}{\left ( t^{2}-\frac{1}{2} \right )\left ( t^{2}-1 \right )}=\frac{1}{2}\left ( \int \frac{dt}{t^{2}-1} -\int \frac{dt}{t^{2}-\frac{1}{2}}\right )=\frac{1}{2}\left [ \frac{1}{2}\left ( \int \frac{dt}{t-1} -\int \frac{dt}{t+1}\right )-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\left ( \int \frac{dt}{t-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} -\int \frac{dt}{t+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\right ) \right ]=\frac{1}{4}\left ( ln\left | t-1 \right |- ln\left | t+1 \right |\right )-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}\left (ln\left | t-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \right |- ln\left | t+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \right |  \right )+C=\frac{1}{4}ln\left | \frac{t-1}{t+1} \right |-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}ln\left | \frac{t-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}{t+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} \right |+C
\end{equation}
So in the end, we have:
\begin{equation}
\int \frac{dx}{cos4x\cdot sin2x}=\frac{1}{4}ln\left | \frac{cos2x-1}{cos2x+1} \right |-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}ln\left | \frac{cos2x-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}{cos2x+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} \right |+C
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

$$\int \frac{dx}{\cos 4x\sin 2x}=\int \frac{\sin 2x}{\left(2\cos^2 2x-1\right)\sin^2 2x}\, dx$$

$$=-\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{1}{\left(2\cos^2 2x-1\right)\left(1-\cos^2 2x\right)}\, d(\cos 2x)$$

Let $u=\cos 2x$.

$$=-\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{1}{\left(2u^2-1\right)\left(1-u^2\right)}\, du$$

Using partial fractions it's very simple:

$$\frac{1}{\left(2u^2-1\right)\left(1-u^2\right)}=\frac{2}{2u^2-1}-\frac{1}{u^2-1}$$

$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}u-1}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}u+1}-\frac{1}{2(u-1)}+\frac{1}{2(u+1)}$$